# Switching CSS Background Image With jQuery On Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a header made that gets slightly smaller on scroll. Currently, the code looks like this for the jQuery involved in the header size:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'small');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '60px'
            }, 600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 600);
        }  
    }
});
```

It is working great, and I have the header size portion down. How can I somewhat replicate this in order to change the size of the logo from roughly 80 x 80 to 40 x 40 (and include the transition)?

Here's the CSS for the logo:

```
#Logo {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 81px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Site URL is http://www.tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html

Answer (score 1):

*edited to include your full code

Your JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'small');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '60px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                height: '40px',
                width: '40px'
            },600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                height: '85px',
                width: '81px'
            },600);
        }  
    }
});
```

And your css:

```
#Logo {
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    width: 81px;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 73;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .5s;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

I'd just like to point out that while jquery does this nice and easily, some (myself included) might consider it preferable to toggle a css class (something like 'smaller') on both the #Header and #Logo and use css to do the resizing and animation.  The css transition would then be:

```
#Header, #Logo {
    transition: height 0.6s, width 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: Changing width/height will cut off the logo (which is a background)

Comment: put background-size:contain on your #Logo css

Comment: Thanks; just so I make sure I do this correctly, can you integrate the code you wrote into what I have already?